# Error:com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: should be set in constructor if stateful,

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, dispatch

I released a APP and this crash error often happened but I have searched the whole internet and cannot find any information about this error.

this is error log track:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: should be set in 
constructor if stateful, stack:
dispatch@436:1078
<unknown>@436:1670
<unknown>@284:210
value@32:1367
value@18:3329
<unknown>@18:912
value@18:2598
value@18:884
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

I think it may happened in one of a dispatch method but there are 100+ dispatch functions in my APP. How to find it ??

Comment: Error appears to come from "react-navigation"
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/d746a587b09676c9ac85d64298340fd5cd0df7e4/src/createNavigationContainer.js#L314

Comment: @SamVK thank you very much. Although I still cannot find the error reason but it's good to know those errors were occurred in react-navigation.